# What is "language of words" means?

Tags: computer-science, terminology

Some papers (especially about Nested Words languages) ofter contain term "language of words". What is the difference between "language" and "language of words"?

Comment: I don't think there is a difference; the author probably wants to insist on the fact that the language is made up of words.

Comment: @zulon: I have same suspicion. But: AFAIK they all made up of words -- what is the point? I do not understand. To make things worse, that wording repeats very often, not just once, and without any comments.

Comment: This would be answered more readily at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com. I think it should be migrated.

Comment: @TheBigO: They will say "This is not _reseach level_ question".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They might be trying to avoid confusion with $\omega$-languages - languages whose elements are infinite sequences of letters ("infinite words"). Such languages have a rich and beautiful theory of their own. I can't think of other possible meanings.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for the pointer; as I already said there are plenty of opportunities to miss entire research areas for every autodidact!